# Display a single value in kibana

Tags: kibana

I am sending with logstash to elasticsearch an event every 30 seconds. This event is called "Test" and has a numeric field "value".
So I have a list of events with the field "value" sometimes changing. For example :
timestamp : 2-04-2014 22:00:30 value : 30 
timestamp : 2-04-2014 22:01:00 value : 35 
timestamp : 2-04-2014 22:01:30 value : 35 
timestamp : 2-04-2014 22:02:00 value : 29 
...

I would like with kibana, to display a box with the label "value" : value where value is always the last value got.
I find histogram to display the evolution of the value over time, but not this single box. If anyone has the solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a "table" panel, set paging to 1 page and 1 document per page, sort by decreasing timestamp and finally pick value as the column to display.

[image]

Here's a screenshot for the table panel settings:

[image]

That will display only the last document's value in that panel.

Comment: I wasnt able to do this successfully (v3.1 kibana). Would you please be able to also show the configuration of the `Panel` tab in "Table Settings" ?

Comment: I added a screenshot for that.

Comment: How would you do the same in Kibana 4?